# recv function always gives me the same buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

This question is kind of a follow-up of a question that I previously asked. Basically I had a c++ server running in ubuntu and I'm now trying to make this code works in windows. I am having some issues with windows socket as it's my first time using them. After some troubles just receiving data on the socket I am now faced with something weird: the buffer that I pass to `recv()` always contains the same data.

Of course, I have checked my client and it does send something different.
So I've been trying my best to get something that would help me figure out what was wrong. I printed on the console the number of bytes received by `recv()` and guess what it is changing as expected ! So I'm a little puzzled now, I don't quite get whu the number of bytes received would be different if the content of the buffer that I pass to recv() is always the same. Would like some help to figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
int tcp_server::acceptConns()
{
    sockaddr_in from;
    bool infinite = true ;
    int fromlen=sizeof(from);
    /* Infinte loop to echo
 the IP address of the client */

    int readsize;
    char* message;
    char* clientmessage = (char*) malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    string smatrix ;
    int ind ;
    string tok;
    int i = 0 ;
    int bytesSent ;

    float matrix[16] ;
     do {
        readsize = recv(ClientSocket, clientmessage, 256, 0);
        if (readsize > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", readsize);
            message = "ack";
            bytesSent = send(ClientSocket, message, strlen(message),0);
            if(bytesSent == 0){
                std::cerr << "Error sending ACK" << endl ;
            }
            smatrix = clientmessage ;
            std::stringstream ss(smatrix);
            while(getline(ss, tok, ',') && i < 16 ){
                matrix[i] = static_cast<float>(::atof(tok.c_str()));
                i++ ;
            }
            coutMessage(matrix);
            message ="ok";
            bytesSent = send(ClientSocket, message, strlen(message),0);
            if(bytesSent == 0){
                std::cerr << "Error sending OK" << endl ;
            }
        }
        else if (readsize == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (readsize > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
     readsize = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
     if (readsize == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Thansk in advance for the help you will provide me.

Comment: Try checking what happens if you put `char* clientmessage = (char*) malloc(256*sizeof(char));` inside the do-while loop.

Comment: This looks more like `C` than `C++`.  `char* clientmessage = (char*) malloc(256*sizeof(char));`  You leak memory every time your function is called.

Comment: Since the size is fixed, you can say `char clientmessage[256];` and not leak.

Comment: @LordZsolt an endless memory leak?

Comment: Doesn't change a thing for me. Within the while loop with putting char `clientmessage[256];` I still get the same message over and over again even though the number of bytes is still different

Comment: Yes, obviously, I'm trying to see if it has something to do with the recv function (which I really doubt) or his container.

Comment: I also doubt that `recv()` is at fault, though I ain't close to figuring out what could possibly be wrong with everything else I've tried so far. I mean if the number of bytes read is different it does that `recv()` gets the correct message but for some reason the message I have in clientmessage is always the first I got from my cleint

Comment: @LonniBesançon maybe the linux server sends you the same data every time... It's hard to tell from here

Comment: That was my first educated guess. But I checked and it doesn't. Besides, the number of bytes read wouldn't be different in that case would it?

Comment: You're assuming that you will always receive exactly one zero-terminated string and nothing else. The data is a stream - you can't assume that there even is a zero, or that there is exactly one. This assumption almost certainly leads to undefined behaviour as you read outside the allocated buffer.

Comment: @LonniBesançon Change this:  `smatrix = clientmessage ;` to this `smatrix = string(clientmessage,readsize)` ;  The reason is that you are to process `readsize` characters.  The second form correctly extracts that number of characters to create the string.  As a matter of fact, you don't use `readsize` at all (except in an `if` statement) when you should be using it to throttle how many characters were actually received.

Comment: I agree, however that was not what was causing my problem here. Besides, so far, I have had this code running for a while on my linux server and things have worked more than well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(getline(ss, tok, ',') && i < 16 ){
    matrix[i] = static_cast<float>(::atof(tok.c_str()));
    i++ ;
}
```

Since you never reset `i`, `matrix` will never be updated after the first time. The `recv` is fine.

Comment: I can't believe I have been so blind to that error for such a long time. I've been searching for ours. I was assuming this part of the code was not at fault since I had already this working on Ubuntu but somehow I forgot to re-write down this line. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.